Showing a basic market admits no arbitrage
Setting
We work in $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\left(\mathcal{F}_t\right)_{t=0}^1, \mathbb{P}\right)$. Let $d=1, T=1$ and assume the discounted price equals the non-discounted price.
Take  $S_0^1 \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, and $S_1^1 \in\left\{\alpha S_0^1, \beta S_0^1\right\}$ each with positive probability s.t. $0<\alpha<\beta$.
Task
I want to show that $\alpha<1<\beta $  iff there is no arbitrage. Additionally I'd like to find an example which shows that if $\mathcal{F}_0$ is not the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, then there exists an arbitrage.
Attempt
I know that for there to be an arbitrage I'd need to find $H_1$ s.t.
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(H_1 \cdot \left(S_1^1-S_0^1\right) \geq 0\right)=1 \text { and } \mathbb{P}\left(H_1 \cdot \left(S_1^1-S_0^1\right)>0\right)>0 .
$$
but I don't know what to base the proof on besides that. I would be grateful for any help!

The idea is actually really simple... presumably the difficulty is in cutting through the abstract formalism. We have an asset whose price is $S_0^1$ and tomorrow it can either go to $\beta S_0^1$ or to $\alpha S_0^1$ where $\beta > \alpha > 0.$ So $\Omega$ has two elements, representing these two outcomes. $H_1$ is the amount we buy or sell today. To have an arbitrage we need a trade we can make in which we'll definitely not lose money and will make money with positive probability. It doesn't take much thought to see that that can only happen if the price is either guaranteed to not go down (i.e. $\alpha\ge1$), or guaranteed not to go up (i.e. $\beta\le 1$). In the former case the arbitrage is we buy (i.e. take $H_1>0$) and in the latter case it is that we sell (i.e. $H_1< 0$).
For the part about $\mathcal F_0,$ since $|\Omega|=2,$ there are only two $\sigma$-algebras... the trivial one $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$, and the full one $P(\Omega).$ If $\mathcal F_0$ is the full $\sigma$-algebra, all the random variables are measurable under $\mathcal F_0$ (i.e. known at the outset), so we already know whether $\beta S_0^1$ or $\alpha S_0^1$ is the price tomorrow. In which case there is an arbitrage where we buy or sell according to whether the price tomorrow is greater than or equal to the price today. (Note it is actually not quite right that there is definitely an arbitrage in this situation, unless neither $\alpha$ nor $\beta$ is equal to $1,$ since otherwise the price tomorrow could equal the price today.) So this part is just a fancy way of expressing the simple idea that if we could predict the future perfectly, we could generally make money risklessly.

thank you, I think I get it now. But do you see a way to prove it more formally? I'm learning math finance on my own and trying to get used to definitions and formalisms there which are new to me
same goes for the $\sigma$-algebra part: I totally understand the reasoning presented but I don't see a way to prove it in a concise/rigorous way

@portero If $\mathcal F_0$ is trivial, the only $\mathcal F_0$-measurable random variables are constants, so $H_1$ must be a constant. It's just an analysis of three cases (1) $\alpha<\beta \le 1 $, (2) $\alpha < 1 < \beta$, (3) $1\le \alpha < \beta$ to show that there is a constant $H_1$ that gives an arbitrage in (1)+(3) but not in (2). If $\mathcal F_0$ is the full $\sigma$-algebra, $H_1$ can be any random variable, e.g. it could be $+1$ if $S_1^1 > S_0^1$ else $1.$
